# How do i deploy a Perfect (swift) backend code + PostgreSQL to Google App Engine

Tags: swift, database, google-app-engine, cloud, perfect

i'm pretty new to web development and much more in Google Cloud, sorry for anything.

Basically, i'm doing the backend part of an app in Swift (using Perfect), and it's running smoothly and okay in my local computer, i'm using a local Postgre database (using PostgreORM in my application).

But, when i deploy that to the Google Cloud, it does not recognize the database (i've created a identical poster database in the computer engine AND a Cloud SQL (Postgre service of Google Cloud with the same names and credentials), but again, when the app is on the cloud, it does not recognize the database, what i'm missing? How should i do it? Install other docker image with Postgre?

Here's my DBConnector code:

```
import PostgresStORM

func setupDBCredentials() -> PostgresConnector.Type{
    let connection = PostgresConnector.self

    connection.host = "localhost" // or the connection name of the Google Cloud, it doesn't work as well
    connection.username = "postgres"
    connection.password = "nearby"
    connection.database = "nearby"
    connection.port = 5432

    return connection
}
```

Basically, how do i make my google app engine code connect to any database at all?

Also, if it helps, i'm using the Perfect Assistant to deploy my code to Google Cloud, using Docker.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to do a few things to get connected, such as granting access to the Cloud SQL instance. [Here is the link to the PHP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql-postgres) that cover the broad steps that you'll want to follow and it shows a representation of the connection string that you'll also need.

I believe your connection string needs to look something like this

```
pgsql:dbname=DATABASE;host=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME
```

Where `CONNECTION_NAME` is in the format of `PROJECT_ID:CLOUD_SQL_REGION_ID:CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_ID`